# ejb starter problem

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I am using JBoss 6.0.1M5.
Starting on EJBs. The tutorial I am reviewing is rather old(talks about 2.0) but I wanted to learn the concepts before going to latest.
Anyway I am using **eclipse** and the javax.ejb.sessionbean can not be located.
I have created a new EJB project and have added the jboss runtime. No problem locating the ejbHome and ejbObject.
Why the javax.ejb.session bean is not found?  Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EJB 3 is *completely* different to EJB 2 - they really have very little in common, and so using an EJB 2.0 tutorial to learn modern EJB isn't going to be of any help.  Also, EJB 2 was just terrible, it's best to try and forget it ever existed.

I suggest you start with the [official JavaEE 5 tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnblr.html) instead.

Comment: Ok I will do that.But in this problem, is javax.ejb.sessionbean removed?I declared ejb2.0 in my eclipse project when I created it.

Comment: @user384706: `javax.ejb.SessionBean` is now considered "expendable", depending which version of JavaEE we're talking about.  It should still be there, although there's no reason to use it any more.

Comment: Only org.jboss.management.j2ee.sessionbean is located. javax.ejb.SessionBean is absent.Jboss libs seem to be there (from the runtime addition).Not sure what I have messed up here....

Comment: @user384706: It's not worth worrying about, `SessionBean` is no longer used in EJB. Move on :)